Finally got "expensive" external training approved, but unsure about staying in current job. How to minimize risks and keep my options open?
I finally got the budget for an "expensive" external training approved by my boss' boss, after a quite bureaucratic process of almost nine months. "Expensive" meaning that the cost of the training exceeds some number X above which a payback clause goes into effect. The payback clause states that if I leave the company within two years of finishing the training, I need to pay (some of) the money back. I have to book the training myself and therefore can control the starting date myself.
Upon reflection in the meantime, I am no longer sure I want to stay with the company for another two years, because I am getting bored with parts of my job. I have been working in my current role for 2.5 years. I am taking the following actions:

Proactively communicating with my boss and team about which projects I want to do and which I don't. This is looked upon positively in my work environment and is fairly normal.
Talking with people in other teams about an internal transfer within our (big) company. Still informal at this stage, but ready to formally apply once the right opportunity arises. I haven't communicated this with anyone except one colleague I trust.
Talking with other companies. Also informal at this stage, but willing to apply once the opportunity arises.

As I see it, my options are:

Delay booking until a job offer arises. I have been doing this for two months, and I feel the time is up. It is not viable any longer.
Going through with the training. This makes applying at a different company more difficult, as I would have to either pay back the training myself, or negotiate with my new employer to cover the costs for me. The new employer covering the payback clause is fairly normal for large corporations, but this might be more tricky for some small startups I've also been talking with. I am taking a personal financial risk or limiting my options.
Not going through with the training. Very suspicious. Potential big career damage and target on my back. What would I even say? I am thinking of quitting and I don't like the repayment clause? No effing way... On top of that: missed career development as I actually still really like the training.
Switching to a very similar training below the repayment threshold. Basically a lesser version of the option above. Suspicious. Weird.

It basically comes down to taking a personal financial risk (or limiting my transfer options for the next two years), or effectively communicating to my manager that my heart is not in it anymore, whereas that is not actually the case, as I do see crafting my current job to the one I want as a viable option, at least for the next 6 months or so.
Is there some other option I am not considering? How can I navigate this situation in a professional way?
Edit: I am leaning towards doing the training, as the financial risk can be minimized by negotiating with a potential new employer. It does limit my options however, as with a startup or freelance I possibly won't be able to negotiate this. The risk of not doing the training seem higher, as I am not prepared to leave right now.

Did it also take 9 months for you to realize you no longer want to be in this company? On one part you say you "I am no longer sure I want to stay with the company for another two years" but then you say "effectively communicating to my manager that my heart is not in it anymore, whereas that is not actually the case, as I do see crafting my current job to the one I want as a viable option" where you basically say that your heart is still on it. Please clarify

I started feeling the urge to apply for other roles only in the last two months or so. But I do see staying on in the team (albeit with a new challenging mix of projects) as a viable option. In my mind, it's not a contradiction: something's got to change, but it could very well be within my current team, although not necessarily.

Thanks for clarifying :) how long would this training take? 6 month perhaps?

Several on-site days over the duration of nine months

I am VTC because this is seeking advice about a specific choice, which is off topic for this site. If you would like to update your question to make it more objective, feel free to do so, as well as edit your title to reflect the actual question you are asking.

@InBedded16 i think this is workable and very answerable (just posted one). Perhaps you saw the "what am I to do?" and instantly associated it to asking for a choice. Although your assessment of that sentence is correct (it asks for us to make a choice for OP), I feel it lacks scope and you are being a bit myopic and square-minded (with all due respect and mod-love). OP is asking us to help them navigate this situation in a way that is best for them. I feel that an edit might help avoid falling into the "what should I" do trap and insta vtc

I changed the title to emphasize that I am looking for the path forward that minimizes risk/damage while keeping options open. Unsure how to make my question more objective, could you help me?

How much would you have to repay, expressed in say "weeks of take home pay"? There's a big difference between risking the cost of a night at an expensive restaurant and risking an amount of money you would have to borrow and pay back over a year or two.

@KateGregory two months of take home pay.

I am honestly a bit surprised this is closed. It presents a workplace dilemma very much like many others on this site. It's essentially, "should I tell my boss I'm leaving" with an added twist of a training that needs to be repaid.

To answer what you say in the title:

but feel like switching jobs which can trigger repayment clause

Yes this definitely will trigger it based on the description you give on your post.

In general I see this is a problem on timing. But you also have to make some self-introspection and think what you really want, what you are willing to do, and what you are not willing to have/do, as that will have much weight on "what you should do".
On comments you clarify that its not that you want to leave asap, but you would like to see some changes on the projects and things you do in order for you to "put your heart back on it". My suggestion in this answer will be a bit of a flow chart:

Priority 1 is to make those new projects you would want a reality ASAP. That is, take the necessary steps to make sure you start shifting to those projects you prefer. If you achieve this, then your dilemma is gone along with the payback worry.
If you do not achieve this, or if getting the projects you prefer will take more time that what you are willing to wait (6 months?), or you see low chances for that to happen, then your options within this company seem limited.

If this is the case, taking the training will surely cause the payback clause to come into play. This may be undesired if you have to pay it from your money.
However, as you mentioned in your point (1) its not rare for companies to pay the previous company for any non-compete or paybacks that may rise from that company "taking you".
Of course, at this point things will be very obvious, and it will be clear that you took the training knowing you would leave, etc.. This may or may not cause some resentment or burn bridges with this company. This may or may not be of importance to you (spec. if you eventually want to come back).




So, perhaps the "smoothest" and best thing for your interest is to ensure that you get the projects you want and the ones that motivate and interest you, as this will avoid all the dilemma and also be something positive for you.
Its important to find that out ASAP, as that will give you time to leave without all these ramifications and what ifs, in the case you realize your current company is no longer a good fit for you.
Good luck!

Thanks for your thoughtful comment. I agree that option (1) (just do the projects I like) can be done right now and is risk-free. The point is, I don't think that will sustain me for the 2,5 years that the repayment clause would effectively "lock" me in.
I am leaning towards doing the training, as the financial risk can be minimized by negotiating with a potential new employer. Downside is that it would potentially limit some of my options.
The downside of not doing the training are high (essentially telling my boss I'm thinking about leaving) and I miss out on a training I want to do.

@tauros_is_the_best_pokemon I see. So it seems that deep inside you seem to feel that regardless of the projects you are assigned in this company you'll never be completely fulfilled or sustain you much time... Your options are narrowing down, unfortunately, to the ones that given the (bad) timing of the situation make them less desirable. I said (bad) because if you suspected this before (at least 2months ago you say), it would have been best to start job-hunting then and there, instead of waiting until you "have to start" the training.

Plus, its 2 years. the 0.5 is the 6month training. Am I reading that this training is also not very fulfilling to you right now? If so, why take it then if you plan to leave? If its fulfilling then you'll have 6 nice months, and then some nice 24months (or less) putting that training to use.

The training is generally applicable also at other employers and I am motivated to do it. However, more direct factors are impacting my willingness to stay (projects, reorganisation). So unfortunately,, "some nice 24 months" enjoying my current work environment seems unrealistic.
